# Download created file by ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have this form in font end:

```
<form id="some_info" method="post" action="#">
    <input type="text" name="info" id="info" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="my_down_action">
    <input type="file" name="test">
    <input id="submit-ajax" name="submit-ajax" type="submit" value="dwonload">
<form>
```

When click submit the ajax sent the form to php function `my_down_action` by this code:

```
var options = { 
    success: showResponse,   
    url:  ajaxurl           
}; 

// bind form using 'ajaxForm' 
$('#some_info').ajaxForm(options); 

function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  {
//download the text
}
```

And this the `php` function:

```
//hook the Ajax call
//for logged-in users
add_action('wp_ajax_my_down_action', 'my_down_action');
//for none logged-in users
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_down_action', 'my_down_action');

function my_down_action(){
    $ttext = $_POST['info'];
    header('Content-Type: application/txt');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=info.txt');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    echo $ttext;
    die();
}
```

How to download the response in ajax ?

Comment: why are you using ajax for this in the first place?

Comment: How to download the response? In [jQuery's ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) you'll get the response in the success method, as the first parameter.

Comment: my downloader has a callback mode activated by bind()ing it with true as the first argument then pre-specifying the name and mime... https://github.com/rndme/download